# Which one is the best practice to get instance in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have read many forums and answers and still, I'm confused with which one is the best and the most used practice to get instance in unity.

```
public static game_code instance;
private void Awake()
{
    instance = this;
}
```

and use this instance in another script like

```
private game_code gameCode;
void Start()
{
    gameCode = game_code.instance; // Do I have to cache the reference if I'm using 
                                   // instance or directly use game_code.instance wherever 
                                   // required in other scripts?
}
```

OR

cache the reference of other scripts in the start like

```
private game_code gameCode; 
void Start()
{
    gameCode=findObjectOfType<game_code>(); // use this reference in script wherever required
}
```

I want to learn the most beneficial way to use this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: For the singleton pattern I suggest you to use the Lazy<T> type which is thread safe. Your solution is it not.

Comment: @MichaelMairegger can I have an example, please?

Comment: I have added an answer. Please see if that solves you issue.

Answer (score 2):

The first method is better , but don't forget to check if you already have the instance created else you might make multiple instances and just need 1.

```
public class SomeClass : MonoBehaviour {
    private static SomeClass _instance;

    public static SomeClass Instance { get { return _instance; } }


    private void Awake()
    {
        if (_instance != null && _instance != this)
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        } else {
            _instance = this;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I have to cache the instance in another script Start method or directly use SomeClass._instance;

Answer (score 1):

you certainly don't want to follow the latter approach unless your project is small as findObjectOfType() would add an overhead of searching the object

so the first approach, that is singleton pattern, is the one that would be most useful when the object is required to be accessed throughout the application among different scripts.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a singleton over the whole application then consider using Lazy since this wrapper ensures thread safety which might be important for concurrent access if the object is not yet initialized

e.g.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private MyClass(){} //prevent creation of class outside this class
    
    private static readonly Lazy<MyClass> _lazyInstance = new Lazy<MyClass>(()=> new MyClass());
    
    public static MyClass Instance => _lazyInstance.Value;
}
```

For more information head to [Lazy Initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/performance/lazy-initialization#thread-safe-initialization)